# Building flutter app remotely through Github Actions Continuous Integration platform cannot find GoogleService-Info.plist file

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, continuous-integration, github-actions

If I build my app in release mode locally it works, but when I try to do it remotely with continuous integration on Github Actions, I get the error:

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
> '/Users/runner/work/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target
> 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Locally the file is in path `/Users/benjamin/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist`. Is the path `/Users/runner/work/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist` potentially incorrect? Any idea how to find out what it should be and how to set it to that? Since it seems kind of like it is trying to store it in the same folder structure but not on my computer. Can I just upload the file to the continuous integration server on Github Actions?

It is run on Github Actions with this workflow file:

flutter-ci.yml:

```
name: Flutter CI

on:
    push:
        branches: [master]
    pull_request:
        branches: [master]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: macos-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
              with:
                  channel: "stable"

            - name: Cache Gradle modules
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              env:
                  cache-number: ${{ secrets.CACHE_NUMBER }}
              with:
                  path: |
                      ~/android/.gradle
                      ~/.gradle/cache
                      # ~/.gradle/wrapper
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ env.cache-number }}-${{ hashFiles('android/build.gradle') }}-${{ hashFiles('android/app/build.gradle') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('android/build.gradle') }}
                      ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-

            - name: Cache CocoaPods modules
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              env:
                  cache-number: ${{ secrets.CACHE_NUMBER }}
              with:
                  path: Pods
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ env.cache-number }}-${{ hashFiles('ios/Podfile.lock') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ env.cache-name }}-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-pods-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-

            - name: Cache Flutter modules
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              env:
                  cache-number: ${{ secrets.CACHE_NUMBER }}
              with:
                  path: |
                      /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter
                      # ~/.pub-cache
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-pub-${{ env.cache-number }}-${{ env.flutter_version }}-${{ hashFiles('pubspec.lock') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-pub-${{ env.flutter_version }}-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-pub-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-

            - name: Get flutter dependencies.
              run: make dependencies

            - name: Check for any formatting and statically analyze the code.
              run: make format-analyze

            - name: Run widget tests for our flutter project.
              env:
                  CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
              run: |
                  make unit-test
                  make codecov

            - name: Build ipa and apk
              run: |
                  flutter precache
                  make build-android-prd
                  make build-ios-prd
```

When that file says "make" it is referencing this make file:

makefile:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:
    flutter channel stable
    flutter upgrade
    flutter pub get
    npm install
    cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..

.PHONY: dependencies
dependencies:
    flutter pub get

.PHONY: analyze
analyze:
    flutter analyze

.PHONY: format 
format:
    flutter format lib/

.PHONY: format-analyze
format-analyze:
    flutter dartfmt -n lib
    flutter analyze

.PHONY: build-runner
build-runner:
    flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

.PHONY: extract-arb
extract-arb:
    flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --suppress-last-modified --output-dir=l10n-arb lib/l10n/message.dart

.PHONY: gen-intl
gen-intl:
    flutter pub pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-use-deferred-loading lib/l10n/message.dart l10n-arb/intl_messages_*.arb

.PHONY: run-dev
run-dev:
    flutter run --flavor development --dart-define=FLAVOR=development --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: run-prd
run-prd:
    flutter run --release --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: build-android-dev
build-android-dev:
    flutter build apk --flavor development --dart-define=FLAVOR=development --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: build-android-prd
build-android-prd:
    flutter build apk --release --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: build-ios-dev
build-ios-dev:
    cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
    flutter build ios --no-codesign --flavor development --dart-define=FLAVOR=development --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: build-ios-prd
build-ios-prd:
    cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
    flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart

.PHONY: unit-test
unit-test:
    flutter test --coverage --coverage-path=./coverage/lcov.info

.PHONY: codecov
codecov:
    ./scripts/codecov.sh ${CODECOV_TOKEN}
```

This is the bit that is failing:

```
.PHONY: build-ios-prd
build-ios-prd:
    cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
    flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart
```

Here is the full information about the error on Github Actions:

```
Run flutter precache
  flutter precache
  make build-android-prd
  make build-ios-prd
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    FLUTTER_HOME: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64
Downloading Android Maven dependencies...                          21.1s
Downloading android-arm-profile/darwin-x64 tools...                 0.5s
Downloading android-arm-release/darwin-x64 tools...                 0.2s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...               0.2s
Downloading android-arm64-release/darwin-x64 tools...               0.1s
Downloading android-x64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...                 0.2s
Downloading android-x64-release/darwin-x64 tools...                 0.1s
Downloading android-x86 tools...                                    1.0s
Downloading android-x64 tools...                                    0.8s
Downloading android-arm tools...                                    0.4s
Downloading android-arm-profile tools...                            0.2s
Downloading android-arm-release tools...                            0.2s
Downloading android-arm64 tools...                                  0.5s
Downloading android-arm64-profile tools...                          0.2s
Downloading android-arm64-release tools...                          0.2s
Downloading android-x64-profile tools...                            0.2s
Downloading android-x64-release tools...                            0.2s
Downloading android-x86-jit-release tools...                        0.3s
Downloading ios tools...                                            1.6s
Downloading ios-profile tools...                                    1.2s
Downloading ios-release tools...                                    6.5s
flutter build apk --release --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleProductionRelease'...              
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/Users/runner/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4/e616dc757061a6a0f83cca53130d72608e2fded5/flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-ae90085a8437c0ae94d6b5ad2741739ebc742cb4.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.

 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/NonNull'

 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'

Note: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-6.3.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleProductionRelease'...                157.0s (!)
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-production-release.apk (42.9MB).
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing Firebase (6.33.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.8.3)
Installing FirebaseAuth (6.9.2)
Installing FirebaseCore (6.10.3)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.7.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (1.18.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.7.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.8.3)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (7.5.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.2)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.11)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing cloud_firestore (0.14.4)
Installing cloud_firestore_web (0.1.0)
Installing firebase_analytics (6.3.0)
Installing firebase_analytics_web (0.1.0)
Installing firebase_auth (0.18.4-1)
Installing firebase_auth_web (0.1.0)
Installing firebase_core (0.5.3)
Installing firebase_core_web (0.1.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing integration_test (0.0.1)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22)
Installing nanopb (1.30906.0)

Installing path_provider (0.0.1)
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Config/Production.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production copy-1.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production copy-1.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Config/Production.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production copy.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production copy.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Config/Production.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Config/Development.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-development copy.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-development copy.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Config/Development.xcconfig`).
Installing path_provider_linux (0.0.1)
Installing path_provider_macos (0.0.1)
Installing path_provider_windows (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 15 dependencies from the Podfile and 32 total pods installed.
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --flavor production --dart-define=FLAVOR=production --target lib/main.dart
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.benjaminfarquhar.vepo for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                             12.4s
Warning: Podfile is out of date
  This can cause issues if your application depends on plugins that do not support iOS.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms for details.
  If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45197 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
  rm ios/Podfile

Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           827.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: warning: dylib (/Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/build/ios/Release-Production-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)
    ld: warning: dylib (/Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/build/ios/Release-Production-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (8.0)
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-6.3.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:49:19: warning: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' is deprecated: Use +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters:] instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverride];
                      ^
    In module 'FirebaseAnalytics' imported from /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:22:
    /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnalytics.h:115:5: note: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:182:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.22.5-stable/x64/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-6.3.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:49:19: warning: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' is deprecated: Use +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters:] instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverride];
                      ^
    In module 'FirebaseAnalytics' imported from /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:22:
    /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnalytics.h:115:5: note: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:182:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:12:26: warning: 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
                             ^
    /Users/runner/work/vepo_getx/vepo_getx/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:11:9: warning: initialization of variable 'flutter_native_splash' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
        var flutter_native_splash = 1
        ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        _
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/runner/work/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'integration_test' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider_macos' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_core_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_analytics_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_auth_web' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider_linux' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider_windows' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.
make: *** [build-ios-prd] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the Google-Info.plist is not available in the provided path. This happens since your username is not the same as the username used by Github actions and also, you have not loaded it to the Downloads directory.
I would suggest checking it into your version control and place it inside the ios directory. Remember to update your references

You could store it somewhere and download it to your Github Actions instance. But loading it directly with the rest of your files is much easier and convenient

#### Warning!

Google-Info.plist can be checked into source control. But others can misuse it if your services are not well protected by security rules. For open source projects, it is suggested to guide others to setup their own Firebase project.
If you are using a private repository then this does not apply.
Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937175/firebase-should-i-add-googleservice-info-plist-to-gitignore)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think this is the only line of code which needs to update after moving the file:

`name = "GoogleService-Info.plist"; path = "../../../../Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };`

The "path" part. Do you know what the filepath of the ios directory in a flutter project would be?

Comment: Oh it is already in "ios/runner/GoogleService-Info.plist" but also in .gitignore. Removing from .gitignore

Comment: In a flutter project (created using `flutter create appName`), the ios folder resides directly inside it. `./ios`. So you should add something like `./ios/GoogleService-Info.plist` or simply `ios/GoogleService-Info.plist`. But remember to check it into your VCS

Comment: I have updated the answer with a warning, please do go through that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this is a private repository.

Comment: Just removed the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from the `.gitignore` and changed the file path inside `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` from `"../../../../Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist"` to `"../runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"`. Then it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)